# Referencing functions defined by subclasses in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, function, flash, oop, subclass

I am setting up a system to manage cutscenes in my game. However, I have run into a tricky problem, and I have a hard time trying to describe it to Google. I need to access a function that Flash tells me is "undefined".

Here's what I'm have;

`Cutscene` is a base class that contains basic functions for all cutscenes

`Cutscene1` extends `Cutscene`, and contains the information about an individual cutscene. Such information includes functions and variables. Later will come `Cutscene2,` `Cutscene3`, all of which extend `Cutscene`

`CutsceneHandler` takes a `Cutscene`, determines the `Cutscene`'s next step, and tells the `Cutscene` to execute the function defined by the step.

`CutsceneHandler` only accepts a `Cutscene`

So we give this handler a newly instantiated `Cutscene1`. Handler says "Hey, it's a `Cutscene`, everything's cool.". But now, the handler tells `Cutscene` to perform a function only defined in its subclass. Handler says "Whoa, the `Cutscene` class has no function like this!" and throws an error. Call to possibly undefined function.

How can we get around this? Is it an issue with how we call the function? I've included some simplified code below.

```
public class CutsceneHandler extends Sprite {

    var activeCutscene:Cutscene

    public function CutsceneHandler() {
        //empty constructor
    }

    public function beginCutscene(cutscene:Cutscene) {
        activeCutscene = cutscene
        executeStep(activeCutscene.steps[0])
    }

    public function executeStep(step:Object) {
        if (step.action) {
            activeCutscene.action()
        }

    }

}
```

__

```
public class Cutscene1 extends Cutscene {

    public var steps = [
              {action:someFunction,someImportantDetail:true},
              {action:someOtherFunction,someImportantDetail:false}
              ]

    public function Cutscene1() {
        //empty constructor
    }

    public function someFunction() {
        trace ("hello!")
    }
    public function someOtherFunction() {
        trace ("goodbye!")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)!

In simple terms, the idea would be to encapsulate the specifics of each step in separate instances of classes which all implement an interface with a single `execute` method. Your handler class can invoke the steps via that interface without any knowledge of the specific subclass of `Cutscene` to which the steps belong.

Something like the following should get you moving in the right direction.

**The ICommand interface:**

```
public interface ICommand {
    function execute():void
}
```

**The concrete commands:**

```
public class HelloCommand implements ICommand {

    public function execute():void {
        trace("hello");
    }
}

public class GoodbyCommand implements ICommand {

    public function execute():void {
        trace("goodbye");
    }
}
```

**The subclass of Cutscene**

```
public class Cutscene1 extends Cutscene {

    // Declare steps variable in the base class since 
    // all subclasses will use it

    public function Cutscene1() {
        // Define the steps specific to this subclass
        steps = [
            new HelloCommand(),
            new GoodbyeCommand()
        ];
    }
}
```

**The handler class**

```
// Only extend Sprite if the class needs to be displayed
public class CutsceneHandler {

    var activeCutscene:Cutscene

    public function CutsceneHandler() {
        //empty constructor
    }

    public function beginCutscene(cutscene:Cutscene) {
        activeCutscene = cutscene;
        // Cast the step as ICommand and execute it
        (activeCutscene.steps[0] as ICommand).execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Though I decided not to use a command pattern, this did introduce me to type casting, which helped me to resolve the problem. Very helpful and detailed response :)